# Схлопывание полей соседних дивов

Tags: html

Хотелось узнать, на самом деле поля у дивов схлопываются только сверху и снизу, а на правые и левые поля это не распространяется?

Comment: Почитайте здесь например:
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy
Или саму спецификацию в переводе:
http://pyramidin.narod.ru/css2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Эта особенность описана в [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) CSS2.1 
  В разделе 8.3.1 в третьем параграфе сказано:

> Horizontal margins never collapse.

То есть горизонтальные отступы никогда не "схлопываются".

Answer (score 0):

[8.3.1 Схлопывание полей](http://resources.webknowledge.ru/specification/8-3-1-shlopyvaniye-poley/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.